# How call keyword throught a keyword withparameters on robot?

Tags: robotframework

I try to factroize my code by using keyword which call many others:

```
perform something_A and otherthing with "$param1" use and "$param2" value
    set something1
    set something2
    set something_B with $param1 and $param2 value
    set something3
    set something4

set something_B with $param1 and $param2 value
    Log smth
    run keyword if    value == smth   so smth
```

In the test I call :

```
perform something10 and otherthing with "param_name_1" use and "value_name_2" value
```

I have error in the first keyword. It cannot reconize the keyword set something20 with 'param1' and '$param2' value
It says keyword not found but I see that the parameters value are loaded on the call.

I tried to change syntax by deleting or adding "" on call or on the keywords name but it not working.

Do you knbow how fix it please? I didn't find this case on the robotcorp documentations.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer your generic question with a generic answer.

I start with the call to the keyword, where the parameters (arguments) are double-quoted):

```
perform "something10" and otherthing with "param_name_1" use and "value_name_2" value
```

(Note: the otherthing is just part of the keyword name because you don't use it)

And the **new keyword** is:

```
*** Keywords ***
perform "${something}" and otherthing with "${param1}" use and "${param2}" value
    Run Keyword If    "${something}" == "something_A"    perform something_A and otherthing with "$param1" use and "$param2" value
```